# Auto start sonar server if not started on jenkins post build

Tags: shell, jenkins, sonarqube

I want to start sonar server if it is not already running. (After I've built my maven project).

```
SERVICE='sonar'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running"
    echo "Starting $SERVICE..."
    $SONAR_HOME start
fi
```

Jenkins returns the following error on the shell script.

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
channel stopped
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/nf/744vmtn93kx6c8kx1rrlnj0r0000gn/T/hudson5680063439912543848.sh
+ SERVICE=sonar
+ ps ax
+ grep -v grep
+ grep sonar
+ echo 'sonar is not running'
sonar is not running
+ echo 'Starting sonar...'
Starting sonar...
+ start
/var/folders/nf/744vmtn93kx6c8kx1rrlnj0r0000gn/T/hudson5680063439912543848.sh: line 10: start: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Skipping sonar analysis due to bad build status FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any ideas why it is failing?

$SONAR_HOME start works fine from terminal command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seemd that $SONAR_HOME not set corretliy ,try to 
eche $SONAR_HOME in sh file and see what happened.